# Collecting polygon features from many people with simple online form?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, data-collection

I work at a transportation consulting firm that works over a large geographic area with dispersed offices. We'd like to develop a database of the locations of our projects, so that we can easily find relevant past projects when starting new work. I'm trying to figure out if this is something we can do using arcgis online.

What I'd like would be a feature service that includes polygons for each project, with attributes for an identifying number and some other information. It would need to be collaborative, so that anyone in the company can contribute features. Ideally, I'd like to create a simple form that others in the company could access through a webpage to submit project info.  This page would use a "draw on the map" input to create shapes, and have some fields for the attributes.

Separately, I'd like to have a map with all features on it that could be queried by users.

I'm familiar enough with collecting features into a feature service using ArcGIS Collector on mobile, and displaying the results on a map or using the service layer in ArcMap. However, there are a few items I'm unsure about:

1. Is there a web-based method for collecting features? (something simpler and more error-resilient than editing a map through the arcgis online interface)
2. Could it be used without logging into arcgis online?
3. Could it be embedded in another webpage, possibly on an intranet?

I'm not sure if this functionality is something that's currently available in arcgis online, or if it would require arcgis server, or if I should be looking outside the esri universe.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Is there a web-based method for collecting features? (something simpler and more error-resilient than editing a map through the arcgis online interface)

Honestly, the ArcGIS Online interface for editing is pretty straight forward in my opinion, but you could use one of their application templates (i.e. the Editor application) if you feel it offers a more intuitive interface.  To do this, add your Feature Service into an ArcGIS Online map.  Save it, and share it by making a web application.  You will see a listing of templates to choose from, and Editor should be on the first page.  You can also download the template if you'd like to customize the application style.

[image: Edit Template]

> 2) Could it be used without logging into arcgis online?

Sure, all you have to do is share the feature service, map and application with Everyone.  That may or may not work for purposes but that is one way to get around the login.

> 3) Could it be embedded in another webpage, possibly on an intranet?

Absolutely.  When you choose to share your map, you can choose the Embed in Application option to get an iframe object of the map document.  Now if you want editing capabilities you will need to either create your own application, or if you create one using the Edit application, simply add the iframe to an existing webpage, just change the SRC URL to the Edit application.

`src="http://my.arcgis.com.domain/apps/Edit/index.html?appid=r232lk24l234j2l34kj23l4k"`

Here is a very quick [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cdoq3ywv/) showing how this can be done.

Earlier in your post you say:

> Ideally, I'd like to create a simple form that others in the company could access through a webpage to submit project info. This page would use a "draw on the map" input to create shapes, and have some fields for the attributes.

If you need people to write/modify attributes of the feature service outside of a map, you'll need to query and [post](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000nv000000) to the service.  You can access the service URL in ArcGIS Online by going to the Feature Service description page and clicking on the drop down arrow next to the layer.

[image: Service URL]

I know there is a lot of information in this post, but it should point you in the right direction for making your web map application.